# How do I add a function to a button that is being created inside another button?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, events

My problem is that I do not know how to add its operation, you see, some buttons will already be programmed and each of them will have the name of the person (installer) and its function will be that when you click, I automatically copy your id , and then with time new installers will emerge and I would love to be able to make my program suitable for normal people and then I think adding a button apart from the installers so they can add more and more, and I need each button created by the person have the functions similar to the others.

Here is my limitation, I do not know where or how your function would go:

```
private void addInstallerActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    JButton newInstaller = new JButton("New Button");
    panel.add(newInstaller);
    validate();
}
```

And here is my whole code:

```
class Billing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        mainWindow w = new mainWindow();
        w.setVisible(true);
        w.setSize(1280,720);
        w.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}

class mainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JPanel panel;
    JButton andresTorres, alexanderHernandez, eduardoRuiz, jorgeFley, addInstaller;
    public mainWindow(){

        panel = new JPanel();
        //Instaladores
        andresTorres = new JButton("Andres Torres");
        alexanderHernandez = new JButton("Alexander Hernandez");
        eduardoRuiz = new JButton("Eduardo Ruiz");
        jorgeFley = new JButton("Jorge Fley");
        addInstaller = new JButton("add Installer");
        //End

        add(panel);

        panel.add(andresTorres);
        panel.add(alexanderHernandez);
        panel.add(eduardoRuiz);
        panel.add(jorgeFley);
        panel.add(addInstaller);

        setTitle("Billing assistant");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        andresTorres.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                andresTorresActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });


        alexanderHernandez.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                alexanderHernandezActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        eduardoRuiz.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                eduardoRuizActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jorgeFley.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                jorgeFleyActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        addInstaller.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                addInstallerActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private void addInstallerActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    JButton newInstaller = new JButton("New Button");
    panel.add(newInstaller);
    validate();
}

    private void andresTorresActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            String myString = "here goes your identification";
            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
            Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
        }

    private void alexanderHernandezActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            String myString = "here goes your identification";
            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
            Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
        }

    private void eduardoRuizActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            String myString = "here goes your identification";
            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
            Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
        }

    private void jorgeFleyActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            String myString = "here goes your identification";
            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
            Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
        }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got too much code redundancy, and not enough OOP -- not enough separate objects that each have its own state and behavior. I recommend:

- First and foremost, create a Person class, one that holds a person's name as a String as well as the id information that you want copied to clipboard associated with that name, as well as any other fields and methods. Make the fields private instance fields, give the class appropriate constructor and getters (and possibly setters).
- Create an ActionListener class (or even better, an AbstractAction, which is like an ActionListener "on steroids") that holds a single Person object in its private field. Pass this Person in via a constructor parameter. In the listener, have code that puts this person's id to the clipboard.

For example in its most simple:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String identification;

    public Person(String name, String identification) {
        this.name = name;
        this.identification = identification;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getIdentification() {
        return identification;
    }

}
```

```
class PersonAction extends AbstractAction {
    private Person person;

    public PersonAction(Person person) {
        super(person.getName());
        this.person = person;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(person.getIdentification());

        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }
}
```

Then in your installer button's ActionListener, you can create buttons with this Action and add them where needed. For example:

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // assuming two JTextFields in the app, nameField and idField
            String name = nameField.getText();
            String identification = idField.getText();

            // create new Person with the name and id information
            Person person = new Person(name, identification);

            // create a new PersonAction with the Person above 
            // and pass into a JButton
            JButton personButton = new JButton(new PersonAction(person));

            // assuming a JPanel called personPanel that holds these JButtons
            personPanel.add(personButton);  // add the button 
            personPanel.revalidate();  // tell the panel to relayout components
            personPanel.repaint();  // and repaint
        }
```

Complete simple example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;    
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainWindowApp2 extends JPanel {
    private JPanel personPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 4, 4));
    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField idField = new JTextField(10);

    public MainWindowApp2() {
        personPanel.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person("Andres Torres", "AT 001"))));
        personPanel.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person("Alexander Hernandez", "AH 002"))));
        personPanel.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person("Eduardo Ruiz", "ER 003"))));
        personPanel.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person("Jorge Fley", "JF 004"))));
        personPanel.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person("Miguél Gonzales", "MG 005"))));

        JButton addInstallerButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add Installer") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String name = nameField.getText();
                String identification = idField.getText();
                Person person = new Person(name, identification);

                JButton personButton = new JButton(new PersonAction(person));
                personPanel.add(personButton);
                personPanel.revalidate();
                personPanel.repaint();
            }
        });

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        topPanel.add(nameField);
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("ID:"));
        topPanel.add(idField);
        topPanel.add(addInstallerButton);

        JPanel personWrapperPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        personWrapperPanel.add(personPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(personWrapperPanel);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        add(scrollPane);
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MainWindowApp2 mainPanel = new MainWindowApp2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainWindowApp2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh brother you are the best, with your beautiful code I will learn much more, Thank you very much!